# Android Material Motion between two activites

Tags: android, material-design, transition

i have two Activities (One with a Recyclerview and a DetailsActvity which will be started with startActvityForResult).

Now i want to make an animation like this when i click on a list item.

https://material.io/guidelines/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-implications-of-motion

it would be great if someone can show me an easy way to realize that.

Comment: http://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition hope this link will help you

Comment: like in preview this isn't a shared element animation. it just has a transtition which starts from the position of clicked item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [makeSceneTransitionAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html#makeSceneTransitionAnimation(android.app.Activity,%20android.view.View,%20java.lang.String)). It is fairly simple to use, you need to have a shared Element on both screens, which has a common XML Tag "transitionName", e.g.

```
"android:transitionName="clock"
```

and then start the activity with the makeSceneTransitionAnimation:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create(clock, "clock");

            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) getContext(), p1);

            mView.getContext().startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

}

**Edit:** I wrote this before you commented that this is not what you are looking for, though I think you can achieve the shown transition with makeSceneTransitionAnimation.

Comment: Thanks, it is working :)

i made i working with `startActivityForResult` with following code:


`ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(activity,  intent,  CategoryDetailsActivity.EDIT_CATEGORY, options.toBundle())`

Comment: now when i close this activity. i want the same animation backward. do you now hot to do this?

Comment: Try to exit the activity with [supportFinishAfterTransition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#supportFinishAfterTransition())